# What to do when a System.IO.IOException occurs while reading from Network stream?

Tags: c#, sockets

What to do when a `System.IO.IOException` occurs while reading from Network stream?

I have this experience of getting this Network IO Exception errors.

One is:

```
System.IO.IOException A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond.
```

I set my `TcpClient's` `SendTimeout` and `ReceiveTimeout` to 10 seconds.
I can read data for the first few hours while `NetworkStream.DataAvailable`.

```
public byte[] Receive()
{
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    byte[] realReceivedBytes = new byte[0];
    try
    {
        if (NetworkStream.CanRead)
        {
            int receivedBytesCount = 0;
            receivedBytesCount = NetworkStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, 1024);
            realReceivedBytes = new byte[receivedBytesCount];
            Array.Copy(readBuffer, 0, realReceivedBytes, 0, receivedBytesCount);
        }
        return realReceivedBytes;
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Sometimes, in the middle of reading data (data is continuously sent by the host once a request is sent), I get the exception error above.

When I ignore that error and continue reading from the stream, the host would reply properly after some time and the error would be gone.

I'm wondering:

1. What causes this error.
2. Why Connected property is false when this error occurs. Does it mean that even if I encounter this error, Connected would be true again (as proved by receiving data again when ignoring the error). So it means it's wrong to check for "Connected" property as my deciding factor to end reading and conclude that the connection was lost?

   ```
   catch (System.IO.IOException)
   {
       if (!client.Connected)
       {
           Log("Client is not connected to host anymore.");
           break;
       }
       else
       {
           Log(String.Format("Error connecting to host. Retry attempt no. {0}",
           (numTries + 1)));
           Thread.Sleep(100);
           numTries++;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Given the situation in 2, how do I proceed when I get an `IOException` error? Aside from that specific error, there was a time I also got:

`System.IO.IOException` Unable to read data from the transport connection. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

which means I really could not recover from the connection and thus needs to close. If I can't distinguish between the two Exception errors, and I cannot use `TcpClient.Connected` to decide to end `Receive()`, how do I differentiate between a recoverable connection and a permanent irrecoverable one? (Aside from comparing the error strings, which I don't like the idea of)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the IOException is thrown by your NetworkStream. However, you socket should also throw exceptions to handle those situations. And those exceptions should be of a different type, allowing you the use the multi-catch syntax.

Comment: @gretro, thanks for your suggestion. I missed MSDN's Note that if we receive an IOException, we should check for the InnerException. Now, I'm implementing multiple catches. But my questions are still the same.

Comment: Up for this question. The errors are verified to be SocketException, but I still have the same questions and problems on how to handle the exceptions.